# I need help in models.py

Tags: python, django

I have an issue in my code I have made coupon system in the website and I want to make sure that client use code only one time and if he enters again did not add the points in his profile any suggestion, I tried to make a list and append the name of the customer if he take the points but it does not work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you provide some code, possibly the part where you tried to use a list to append the name of the customer?

Comment: it is the first time i treate with stack overflow so i did not know how present code
i made a list =[] in the function that make apply code and foreach user implement coouponit append his name in list

Comment: Copy your relevant code, then paste it into your question.  highlight the code and press the {} button at the top of the edit widget

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean for all codes.

Create a BooleanField for every code. And change it to true/false if was successfully used.

Comment: i made a code charfield to class trader and in the views.py i check if coupon.code == trader.code return to the page with message warning else trader.points=trader.points+int(coupon.points) and trader.code = coupon.code so in the next time will not add the points